# How to remove BorderThickness and Effect when clicking outside WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom Style for textbox, I apply DropShadowEffect and a border in this textbox, I would like to remove the effect of both the border and the Shadow when user clicks outside the wpf.

For example if a user has wpf open and clicks on the windows desktop, wpf should remove the border and shadow.

My Style:

```
<Style x:Key="MTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" Color="Red" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="2"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try property "IsKeyboardFocused" instead of "IsFocused" in your second trigger.